# OpenGL is rendering just texture, not lines (probably simple)

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I have implemented my "engine", which used to draw lines nicely. But now, after I have implemented simple sprites, lines are not rendering anymore (but sprite does). Everything went wrong when I put glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D) in my initalization code.

```
glClearColor(0.0f,0.0f,0.0f,0.0f);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glEnable( GL_BLEND );
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity(); 
glOrtho(0, width, 0, height, 1, -1);
```

My lines are drawn following way:

```
    glLineWidth(lineWidth);
    glColor4f(color.getR(), color.getG(), color.getB(), color.getA());
    if(transformToViewport) {
        Point a = vp.transformCoords(begin);
        Point b = vp.transformCoords(end);
        glVertex3f(a.coords[0], a.coords[1], 0);
        glVertex3f(b.coords[0], b.coords[1], 0);
    }
    else {
        glVertex3f(begin.coords[0], begin.coords[1], 0);
        glVertex3f(end.coords[0], end.coords[1], 0);
    }
```

And sprite:

```
    float transformedH = vp.transformLength(height);
    float transformedW = vp.transformLength(width);
    Point transformedCenter = vp.transformCoords(center);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureID());

    glTexCoord2f(0f, 1f);
    glVertex2f(transformedCenter.coords[0] - transformedW / 2, transformedCenter.coords[1] - transformedH / 2);

    glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
    glVertex2f(transformedCenter.coords[0] + transformedW / 2, transformedCenter.coords[1] - transformedH / 2);

    glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
    glVertex2f(transformedCenter.coords[0] - transformedW / 2, transformedCenter.coords[1] + transformedH / 2);


    glTexCoord2f(1f, 1f);
    glVertex2f(transformedCenter.coords[0] + transformedW / 2, transformedCenter.coords[1] - transformedH / 2);

    glTexCoord2f(1f, 0f);
    glVertex2f(transformedCenter.coords[0] + transformedW / 2, transformedCenter.coords[1] + transformedH / 2);

    glTexCoord2f(0f, 0f);
    glVertex2f(transformedCenter.coords[0] - transformedW / 2, transformedCenter.coords[1] + transformedH / 2);


    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

Comment: Disable `GL_TEXTURE_2D` before you draw your lines. Line primitives can be texture mapped too, as weird as that may sound to you. Making matters worse, each of your line's vertices have identical texture coordinates (I cannot say what they are from this context, but each one has the same).

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: I have read about that rendering to texture, but only a little bit. I have searched for glowing effect for lines and it render to texture is needed. But that is now far far away over my actual needs. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);` prior to drawing textures (e.g. in the method), and then immediately after, use `glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);`.

For beginners (and some times for more complex systems), it is good to pair up `glEnable` and `glDisable` calls together to prevent unnecessary capabilities from being used for things (and in some cases causing issues, like this) that you don't need them for.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Problem was, that I have only enabled textures once in initialization of Engine. After that, I have tried to pair it between glBegin and glEnd. And you are right, it has to be done prior to rendering. Thanks again.

Comment: @OndřejHolman: You do not want to do that either, there are only a few commands that are valid between `glBegin (...)` and `glEnd (...)` and they are all related to specifying vertex attributes. You should enable / disable the texture immediately before or after the begin/end pair if you take that approach.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: Sorry, I think it was only because of my English. By prior to rendering I meant before glBegin and after glEnd. :-) I just wanted to say, I have done it incorrectly before, when I was trying to get it working. Thanks!